# How do I get jQuery Mobile to re-execute on generated code?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to generate some jQuery Mobile elements with Javascript.  After the javascript runs and places the generated elements in the `myTest` div, the styling and scripting are not attached as they are on the static content.  Is there any way to have jQuery execute on the generated code?

Here's an example:

Markup:

```
<!-- Does not look correct when populated -->
<div id="myTest">
</div>

<!-- Looks correct -->
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="d" data-content-theme="d" data-mini="true" data-corners="false">
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Test</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(onloadFunc);

function onloadFunc() {
  var parent = $('<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="d" data-content-theme="d" data-mini="true" data-corners="false">');
  var item = $("<h3>").html("test");
  parent.append(item);
  $("#myTest").append(parent);
}
```

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DcFhj/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off your markup is actually slightly off, the [collapsible-set](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible-set/) widget is meant to contain within it several collapsible widgets.

For example (taken from the [documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible-set/))

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
  <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
   <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 1.</p>
   </div>
   <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Have a look at the following *[question](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/faq/injected-content-is-not-enhanced.html)* from the jQuery Mobile documentation. Basically in general in order to enhance markup that is dynamically inserted you have to either initialize the widget on the markup or you can trigger the `create` event on a parent element and jQuery Mobile should initialize all of the appropriate widgets.

In this case being that you just have one widget you just need to initialize the [collasible](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/) widget (also interesting enough this works with your current markup)

```
$("#myTest").append(parent).find('div').collapsible();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DcFhj/3/

If for example you had several widgets that needed enhancement (or just for simplicity) you could instead trigger the create method (this doesn't work with your current markup but if you correct it it should).

```
 $("#myTest").append(parent).trigger('create');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DcFhj/4/

Comment: I don't think that does anything.  This should work if that were the case, right?:  http://jsfiddle.net/DcFhj/2/

Comment: Sorry you need to call it on the div with the collapsible-set data-role, not the parent div. I updated my post.

Comment: Something else I should point out is that if you have many widgets that need to be initialized you should be able to just trigger the create event on the page for example `$('#myJQMPage').trigger('create')`, but I'm not sure where it is in the current documentation.